# Applying Multiple Window Functions in 1 SELECT using different partition

Tags: sql-server, window-functions, running-totals

I was wondering if there is anything wrong with using this method.

I have a working demo of what i'm trying to do below

In the `SELECT` statement I have used 2 `OVER` clauses.

Is there any risk that the data could get out of sequence?

```
CREATE TABLE basic_pays (
    employee_id int,
    fiscal_year INT,
    salary DECIMAL(10 , 2 ),
    PRIMARY KEY (employee_id, fiscal_year)
);

INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(100,2017,24000);
INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(101,2017,17000);
INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(102,2017,18000);
INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(103,2017,9000);
INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(100,2018,25920);
INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(101,2018,18190);
INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(102,2018,18360);
INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(100,2020,26179.2);
INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(101,2020,19463.3);
INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(102,2020,19278);
INSERT INTO basic_pays(employee_id, fiscal_year,salary) VALUES(103,2020,10206);

SELECT 
    employee_id, 
    fiscal_year,
    salary, 
    LAG(salary) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY fiscal_year) previous_salary,
    SUM(salary) /SUM(SUM(salary))
        OVER (PARTITION BY fiscal_year ORDER BY fiscal_year) salary_percentage
FROM
    basic_pays
GROUP BY 
    employee_id, fiscal_year, salary
ORDER BY fiscal_year, employee_id

DROP TABLE basic_pays
```

Comment: A couple of things don't seem to make sense. 1. `salary` is part of the grouping criteria and yet you are aggregating it (`SUM(salary) / SUM(SUM(salary)) OVER (...)`). I think doing it like this would give you the same results: `salary / SUM(salary) OVER (...)` 2. What do you mean by `PARTITION BY fiscal_year ORDER BY fiscal_year`? There'll be just one `fiscal_year` per partition of `fiscal_year`. Perhaps you could elaborate a little on the logic you are trying to implement?

Answer (score 1):

That should be fine.

Your first column (`LAG(salary)`) will be calculated over the partition you specified, which the second column will be calculated over the second partition.

Note that each partition specifies its own `ORDER BY` clause - so your windowed functions are calculated based on your row's position within the partition and its own `order by` clause.

I can't see any issues with this.

When you run it, do you get the results you expect?